# Formating an Object as a neatly looking List

Tags: list, powershell, object, format, output

I'm trying to output the objects as such:

[image: Preferred output]

Piping the variable containing the objects thru `Format-List` produces empty lines which creates problems. I'm not able to remove the empty lines for some reason when using `$obj = $obj | ? {$_}`

I expect the variable containing the objects to contain the right count of objects.

Interesting enough when I run `$Host` first (which has the formatting I'm looking for) and then run the variable `$obj`, then I get the results I'm looking for.

Any help is much appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
$String = @"


   FileName: O:\iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii
iiiiiiiiiiiiiii.txt

:`$DATA                                      9
SummaryInformation                       128
{4c8cc155-6c1e-11d1-8e41-00c04fb9386d}      0




   FileName: O:\ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
sssssssssssssss.txt

:`$DATA                                      9
SummaryInformation                       128
{4c8cc155-6c1e-11d1-8e41-00c04fb9386d}      0




   FileName: 
O:\aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.txt

:`$DATA      0
Lzip        7



"@

[regex]$pattern1 = '(?s)\s+FileName:\s+(?<FullName>.*?)\s+:\$DATA'
$Match1 = $String | Select-String -Pattern $pattern1 -AllMatches |
          % { $_.Matches }  

[regex]$pattern2 = '(?sm)(?:(?<Stream>^:\$DATA.*?)\s+FileName|(?<Stream>^:.*))'
$Match2 = $String | Select-String -Pattern $pattern2 -AllMatches |
          % { $_.Matches }

$obj = 0..($Match1.Count -1) | % {    
    New-Object -TypeName PsObject -Property @{
        FullName = $Match1[$_].Groups['FullName'].Value
        Streams  = $Match2[$_].Groups['Stream'].Value
    }
}

$obj
```

Edit: Here is the output I get even when removing line breaks as suggested:

```
FullName
--------
O:\iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii...
O:\ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss...
O:\aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.txt
```

Comment: Try the Trim method to remove extra white spaces.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm dealing with objects, not a string. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Please show an example of your desired output. Apparently it's not what you showed in the screenshot at the beginning of your question.

Comment: My desired output is in the screenshot itself. I'm looking for a list, not a table. When I use Format-List like <$Newobj = $obj | Format-List> it adds empty lines. I want each object to have the properties FullName and Streams and I want the variable containing the List of objects with the proper count (3) and showing as a list. The problem is not when creating the object because I can see with <($obj | measure).count> that the table contains 3 counts. The problem is the output of the object. I want the output to come out as what is shown in the screenshot: a list.

Comment: `$obj | Format-List` generates the output from your screenshot. What are you talking about?

Comment: I understand. `$List = $obj | fl` creates empty items for me and that is problematic, the count will be more than 3 with the additional items being empty and that is what I can't seem to get rid off from the variable. That's that make sense? On certain occasions I don't have the recur to using Format-List, the output of the object will already come out as a list and that is what I don't understand. Typing $Host and then $obj will result in the output I need without using Format-List, and without any empty entries.

Comment: To assign the formatted output sans blank lines to a variable use something like this: ``$List = ($obj | Format-List | Out-String).Trim() -replace '\n\s*\n', "`n"``

Comment: Thank you for your effort. The problem is that by converting the variable into a string I'd loose the count. The question is why doesn't this work? `$List = $List | ? { $_ }`.

Comment: Probably because you're misunderstanding what [`Format-List`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849957.aspx) does. Take a look at the output of `$obj | % {$_.GetType().FullName}` and `$obj | Format-List | Get-Member`. Converting the objects individually (`$obj | % {($_ | fl | Out-String).Trim()}`) might give you what you want, but since you're still losing the structural information from the objects, I fail to see how that'd be more useful than the original string from where you got the data in the first place.

Comment: My advice would be: keep your data in objects as long as possible and do formatting only when you actually need to display/write output. Do not format intermediate data.

Answer (score 0):

You don't remove linebreaks from the filenames you parsed from the string. That's most likely why your list output doesn't wrap the way you want it to.

Change this:

```
$obj = 0..($Match1.Count -1) | % {    
    New-Object -TypeName PsObject -Property @{
        FullName = $Match1[$_].Groups['FullName'].Value
        Streams  = $Match2[$_].Groups['Stream'].Value
    }
}
```

to this:

```
$obj = 0..($Match1.Count -1) | % {    
    New-Object -TypeName PsObject -Property @{
        FullName = $Match1[$_].Groups['FullName'].Value -replace '[\r\n]+'
        Streams  = $Match2[$_].Groups['Stream'].Value
    }
}
```

and the problem should disappear.